# How to read and extract data from multiple files in a folder into csv/xls?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv

I have a folder that has many files (not just TXTs). I want to be able to sort the files and Pythonically read each file line by line and insert the data into a csv file. The data is raw and doesn't have columns. For some reason I am only getting one file. (Looping through many files line by line the inserting it into a file)

The data is basically Time stamp, error number, - status (no comma)updated time completed(boolean) location. This is how the data is on most lines

Here is what I started with:

```
import xlwt
import os

direct = r"home/myname/docs/data"
listoffiles = [os.listdir(direct)]

for d in listoffiles:
    name = direct+ '/' + /str(d)
    w = open(name)
    for lines in w:

    opt = [a.strip() for a in lines.split(' ')]
```

I've been trying to get each line to out put like this before inserting into a csv or xls. ["","" ,"",""] (line one file one), ["","" ,"",""] (line two file one), ["","" ,"",""] (line three file two), and so forth.

This is what I have so far.

I would appreciate some assistance with such matter.

Comment: You need to describe the format of the data being read precisely—just saying it's "raw and doesn't have columns" is too vague.

Comment: Sorry. The data is basically Time stamp, error number, - status (no comma)updated time completed(boolean)  location. This is how the data is  on most lines.

Comment: Still a bit too vague in my opinion. Please [edit] your question and add some sample data (a few lines) from one of the files to it (indenting each of the lines by 4 spaces like it was code).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to select all the files. Then you can simply read the file and extract the data to a csv.

You can pass a key to the `sorted` function to the file names in whatever way you want to.

```
 import glob
 import csv
 import os

 csv_writer = csv.writer( open( "csv_output.csv", "w" ) )
 file_list  = []

 os.chdir("/home/myname/docs/data")
 for file in glob.glob("*"):
      file_list.append( file )

 file_list = sorted( file_list )

 for file in file_list:
      file_data = open( file, "r" ).read()
      row = [ file, file_data ]
      csv_writer.writerow( row )
```

Comment: `glob.glob()` doesn't return a sorted list of filenames which is what the OP wants. They also said the files are "raw", so it's very unlikely that sending the entire contents of one as a single row via one call to `csv.writer.writerow()` would work.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the changes you've suggested. What alternative would you recommend for sending the "raw" input then ?

Comment: the `chdir` doesn't seem to be needed; why not just pass the whole path to `glob`?

Comment: That's better (although you could have just used `for file in sorted(glob.glob("*"))`. To handle the "raw" data requires knowing its exact format—which the OP hasn't completely specified—and then massaging it into something that `writerow()` (or maybe `writerows()`) would accept as input.

Comment: The first part totally helped. I am still trying to get the data line by line split so that the striped data within the lines are line ['','',''],['','',''] before inserting into a CSV/XLS Meghdeep Ray

Comment: @J.Ballard: A description of the output desired isn't needed, since it's fairly obvious given you want to create a csv file. What is needed is knowledge of **exactly** the format of the input files. What part of my earlier suggestion of putting a few lines from one of these files into question didn't you understand? Help us help you.